# Ruby Count Array objects if object includes value

Tags: ruby, arrays, count

I have an array:

```
array = ['Footballs','Baseball','football','Soccer']
```

and I need to count the number of times Football or Baseball is seen, regardless of case and pluralization.

This is what I tried to do, but with no luck:

```
array.count { |x| x.downcase.include? 'football' || x.downcase.include? 'baseball' }
```

What is a right or better way to write this code? I am looking for 3 as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use `count` combined with a block that checks each element against a regular expression that matches the constraints you're looking for. In this case:

```
array.count { |element| element.match(/(football|baseball)s?\Z/i) }
```

This will match any of these elements: football, footballs, baseball, baseballs.

The `s?` makes the 's' optional, the `i` option (`/i`) makes the expression case insensitive, and the `\Z` option checks for the end of the string.

You can read more about Regexps in the Ruby docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html

A great tool for playing with Regexps is Rubular: http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you give a block to the count method of array, it iterates over the array and counts the values for which you return true:

```
array.count do |x|
  (x.downcase.include? 'footbal') || (x.downcase.include? 'baseball')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to count each item and return the result.

```
array = ['Football','Baseball','football','Soccer']

count = array.inject({}) do |counter, item|
  counter[item.downcase] ||= 0
  counter[item.downcase]  += 1
  counter
end

# => {"football"=>2, "baseball"=>1, "soccer"=>1}
```

If you need to count a single value, it's even simpler.

```
array = ['Football','Baseball','football','Soccer']

count = array.inject(0) do |counter, item|
  counter += (item.downcase == 'football' ? 1 : 0)
end
```

On one line

```
array = ['Football','Baseball','football','Soccer']

count = array.inject(0) { |counter, item| counter += (item.downcase == 'football' ? 1 : 0) }
```

To include pluralization, simply enhance the comparison.

Comment: Simone_, with regard to the hash `count` that you've created (and in other similar situations), consider using `each_with_object` rather than `inject`.  By doing so, you don't need to return the object you've created to the iterator (`counter` at the end).  Also, if you create the hash with new values defaulting to zero, you don't need check to see if a key already exists.  Apply these two suggestion here, we get: `array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|item, counter| counter[item.downcase] += 1}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Ruby on Rails installed for the `singularize` method (you don't actually need to run this in rails):

```
require 'active_support/inflector'

array = ['Footballs','Baseball','football','Soccer']
uniq = array.map { |s| s.downcase.singularize }.uniq

uniq.size # => 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Rails` and `Ruby >= 2.7` you can do:

```
array = ['Footballs','Baseball','football','Soccer']
array.map(&:downcase).map(&:singularize).tally
=> {"football"=>2, "baseball"=>1, "soccer"=>1}
```